# Filter TextBox value disappear after postback telerik:RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I am trying to filter data by column but after postback the data is getting removed from textbox

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="DynamicTestCaseReport.aspx.vb" Inherits="DynamicTestCaseReport" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/TM32.ico" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/TestMagic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <sript runat="server"></sript>

    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

    <table id="tblData" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0" runat="server">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="rowlblError" runat="server" align="center">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" CssClass="LabelMessage">
                    </asp:Label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="Title">
                <asp:Label ID="lblDisplayHeader" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" CssClass="LabelMessage"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

                <asp:Label ID="lblTemplate" runat="server" Text="Template Name : "></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboTemplate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboTemplate_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    CssClass="text1" Width="200px">
                </asp:DropDownList>

            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <asp:CheckBoxList Width="100%" runat="server" ID="chkFields" DataTextField="Column_name"
                    DataValueField="Column_name" ToolTip="Please select data fields for report generation."
                    RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" BorderStyle="Solid"
                    TextAlign="Right" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="Black" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <table style="width: 990px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTemplateName" runat="server" Text="Enter Template Name : "></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTemp" runat="server" MaxLength="100" Columns="22" Width="150"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSaveTemplate" runat="server" Text="Save Template" CssClass="BigBtn" />
                        </td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-left: 200px;">

                            <asp:Button ID="btnShowGrid" runat="server" Text="Generate"
                                CssClass="NormalBtn" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel"
                                CssClass="NormalBtn" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>


            </td>

            <%--      <td align="left" style="padding-right: 200px;">
                <asp:Button ID="btnShowGrid" runat="server" Text="Generate"
                    CssClass="NormalBtn" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel"
                    CssClass="NormalBtn" />
            </td>--%>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="padding-top: 10px;">

                <div id="gridDiv" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; overflow: scroll;">

                    <telerik:RadGrid ID="gridData" runat="server" Visible="true" OnGridExporting="grid_GridExporting">
                    </telerik:RadGrid>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <div id="gridDiv1" runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnEmailReport" runat="server" Text="Email Report"
                        CssClass="BigBtn" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnExcel" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel"
                        CssClass="BigBtn" />
                   <asp:Button ID="btnECSV" runat="server" Text="Export to CSV"
                        CssClass="BigBtn" />
                      <asp:Button ID="btnEPDF" runat="server" Text="Export to PDF"
                        CssClass="BigBtn" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

CS code i have done necessary setting if not please correct me :

```
    Partial Class DynamicTestCaseReport
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim objGeneral As TestMagic.General
    Protected Form1 As New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm
    Dim flag As Boolean = False
    Dim flagcheck As Boolean = False
    Dim common As TestMagic.General = New TestMagic.General()
    Dim ServerPath As String = Server.MapPath("ReportViewer")

#Region " Web Form Designer Generated Code "

    'This call is required by the Web Form Designer.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()

    End Sub
    Protected WithEvents lbldata As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label

    Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
        'CODEGEN: This method call is required by the Web Form Designer
        'Do not modify it using the code editor.
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

#End Region


    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) ' Handles MyBase.Load
        'Put user code to initialize the page here
        ServerPath = common.ReadResourceFileaddress(ServerPath)
        If Not IsPostBack Then

            'Dim ServerPath As String = Server.MapPath("ReportViewer")


            Dim objAdmin As New Admin()
            Dim allCloumn As New DataSet
            allCloumn = objAdmin.GetAllColumsFromDB()
            FillTemplate()

            If allCloumn Is Nothing Then
                gridDiv.Visible = False
                gridDiv1.Visible = False
                btnShowGrid.Enabled = False
                btnCancel.Enabled = False
                lblError.Text = common.ReadResourceValue(ServerPath, "ReportrelatedTableisnotpresentinDataBase")
                Exit Sub
            End If

            chkFields.DataSource = allCloumn
            chkFields.DataBind()
            Session.Add("myDataGrid", gridData)
            'chkFields.Items(0).Enabled = False
            'chkFields.Items(0).Selected = True

            Dim intVal As Integer = chkFields.Items.Count
            'For a = 0 To intVal - 1
            '    chkFields.Items(a).Selected = True
            'Next  
            Session("DynamicResultReportGridData") = Nothing
        End If

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds = Session("DynamicResultReportGridData")
        If Not ds Is Nothing Then
            DefineGridStructure(Session("DynamicResultReportGridData"))
            gridData.DataBind()
            gridDiv.Visible = True
            gridDiv1.Visible = True
            btnShowGrid.Enabled = True
            btnCancel.Enabled = True
        Else
            gridDiv.Visible = False
            gridDiv1.Visible = False
            'btnShowGrid.Enabled = False
            'btnCancel.Enabled = False
            'lblError.Text = "Report related Table is not present in DataBase."
        End If



        lblDisplayHeader.Text = common.ReadResourceValue(ServerPath, "CustomizeTestCaseResultReport") 'common.ReadResourceValue(ServerPath, "TestCaseResultReport")

    End Sub


    Protected Sub btnShowGrid_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowGrid.Click

        Try
            Dim objAdmin As New Admin()
            Dim allCloumnData As New DataSet
            gridDiv.Visible = False
            gridDiv1.Visible = False
            allCloumnData = objAdmin.GetAllDataFromTestCaseResult()
            Dim intVal As Integer = chkFields.Items.Count
            If allCloumnData Is Nothing Then
                lblError.Text = common.ReadResourceValue(ServerPath, "ReportrelatedTableisnotpresentinDataBase") & common.ReadResourceValue(ServerPath, "PleaseAddColumnsfirst")
                Exit Sub
            Else
                lblError.Text = ""
            End If
            For a = intVal - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If Not chkFields.Items(a).Selected Then
                    allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns.RemoveAt(a)
                End If
            Next

            If Not allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns.Count > 0 Then
                lblError.Text = common.ReadResourceValue(ServerPath, "Pleaseselecttherequiredcolumnstogeneratethereport")
                Exit Sub
            Else
                lblError.Text = ""
            End If

            'INSERT Identity column
            Dim dc As New DataColumn("ID_Data")
            dc.AutoIncrement = True
            dc.AutoIncrementSeed = 1
            dc.AutoIncrementStep = 1
            allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns.Add(dc)

            'Set values for existing rows
            For i As Integer = 0 To allCloumnData.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                allCloumnData.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("ID_Data") = i + 1
            Next


            gridDiv.Visible = True
            gridDiv1.Visible = True
            DefineGridStructure(allCloumnData)
            gridData.DataBind()

        Catch ex As Exception
            lblError.Text = "Error : " & ex.Message.ToString()
        End Try

    End Sub
    Protected Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click

        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
    End Sub




    Protected Sub btnEmailReport_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEmailReport.Click
        gridDiv.Visible = True
        gridData.Visible = True
        flag = True
        Dim data As New DataSet
        data = Session("DynamicResultReportGridData")
        DefineGridStructure(data)
        gridData.Rebind()

        gridData.ExportSettings.Excel.Format = GridExcelExportFormat.Biff
        gridData.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = True
        gridData.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = False
        gridData.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = True

        gridData.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel()

    End Sub


    Protected Sub grid_GridExporting(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As GridExportingArgs)
        If flag Then
            'Dim filename As String = "TestCaseResultReport.xls"
            Dim strDateTime As String = Date.Now.ToString()
            strDateTime = strDateTime.Replace("/", "")
            strDateTime = strDateTime.Replace(" ", "_")
            strDateTime = strDateTime.Replace(":", "-")
            Dim filename As String = "TestCaseResultReport_" & strDateTime & ".xls"
            Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~/PDFReport/") + filename
            Using fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)
                Dim info As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.[Default].GetBytes(e.ExportOutput)
                fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
            End Using

            Response.Redirect("EmailReport.aspx?docID=" & filename & "&ids=dy")
        End If
    End Sub




    Private Function Company_Excel() As String
        Return ""
    End Function


    Protected Sub btnEPDF_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEPDF.Click
        'gridDiv.Visible = True
        'gridData.Visible = True

        Dim data As New DataSet
        data = Session("DynamicResultReportGridData")
        'DefineGridStructure(data)

        ''grid.ExportSettings.Pdf.AllowPrinting = True
        'gridData.ExportSettings.Pdf.PaperSize = GridPaperSize.Letter
        'gridData.ExportSettings.Pdf.PageWidth = 1500
        ''grid.ExportSettings.Pdf.PageTitle = "Users"
        ''grid.ExportSettings.Pdf.AllowModify = True
        ''grid.ExportSettings.Pdf.AllowCopy = True

        'gridData.ExportSettings.Pdf.FontType = Telerik.Web.Apoc.Render.Pdf.FontType.Embed

        'gridData.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = True
        'gridData.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = False
        'gridData.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = True

        'ApplyStyleSheetExportPDF(gridData.MasterTableView)
        'gridData.MasterTableView.ExportToPdf()

        Dim General As New TestMagic.General()
        Try
            Dim objDefectManagement_ExportToPDF As New DefectManagement_ExportToPDF()
            objDefectManagement_ExportToPDF.ProjectName = Convert.ToString(Session("Project"))
            'objDefectManagement_ExportToPDF.SubProjectName = Convert.ToString(Session("SubProject"))
            ' objDefectManagement_ExportToPDF.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ViewState("StartDate")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
            ' objDefectManagement_ExportToPDF.EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ViewState("EndDate")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")


            Dim pdfName As String = objDefectManagement_ExportToPDF.ExportToPDF_ManageDefects(True, data.Tables(0), "CustomizeTestCaseResultReport")
        Catch ex As Exception
            rowlblError.Visible = True
            lblError.Text = General.ReadResourceValue(ServerPath, "GeneralexceptionoccurredwhileretrievingPDFReport")
        End Try


    End Sub



    Protected Sub btnExcel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExcel.Click
        gridDiv.Visible = True
        gridData.Visible = True

        Dim data As New DataSet
        data = Session("DynamicResultReportGridData")
        DefineGridStructure(data)
        gridData.Rebind()
        gridData.ExportSettings.Excel.Format = GridExcelExportFormat.Biff

        gridData.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = True
        gridData.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = False
        gridData.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = True

        For Each item As GridNoRecordsItem In gridData.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.NoRecordsItem)
            item.Display = False
        Next

        gridData.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub btnECSV_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnECSV.Click
        gridDiv.Visible = True
        gridData.Visible = True

        Dim data As New DataSet
        data = Session("DynamicResultReportGridData")
        DefineGridStructure(data)
        gridData.Rebind()
        gridData.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = True
        gridData.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = False
        gridData.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = True
        gridData.MasterTableView.ExportToCSV()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DefineGridStructure(ByVal allCloumnData As DataSet)

        'Dim grid As New RadGrid()

        gridData.DataSource = allCloumnData
        Session.Add("DynamicResultReportGridData", allCloumnData)
        gridData.Skin = "Default"
        gridData.Width = Unit.Percentage(100)
        gridData.PageSize = 15
        gridData.AllowPaging = True
        gridData.AllowFilteringByColumn = True
        gridData.PagerStyle.Mode = GridPagerMode.NextPrevAndNumeric
        gridData.AutoGenerateColumns = False

        'Add Customers table
        gridData.MasterTableView.Width = Unit.Percentage(100)

        If gridData.MasterTableView.Columns.Count > 0 Then
            For a = gridData.MasterTableView.Columns.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                gridData.MasterTableView.Columns.RemoveAt(a)
            Next

        End If

        gridData.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames = New String() {"ID_Data"}

        Dim intVal As Integer = allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns.Count
        For a = 0 To intVal - 2
            Dim boundColumn As New GridBoundColumn()

            boundColumn.DataField = allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns(a).Caption().Trim().ToString()
            boundColumn.HeaderText = allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns(a).Caption().Trim().ToString()
            boundColumn.UniqueName = allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns(a).Caption().Trim().ToString()
            boundColumn.ItemStyle.CssClass = "text2"

            boundColumn.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "GridHeader"
            boundColumn.AllowFiltering = True
            gridData.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn)
        Next


    End Sub

    Protected Sub grid_NeedDataSource(ByVal Source As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs) Handles gridData.NeedDataSource

        gridDiv.Visible = True
        gridDiv1.Visible = True
        gridData.Visible = True
        Dim allCloumnData As DataSet = Session("DynamicResultReportGridData")
        gridData.DataSource = allCloumnData

    End Sub

    'To Save Tempate Details
    Protected Sub btnSaveTemplate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveTemplate.Click
        Dim objAdmin As New TestMagic.Admin()
        Dim dsData As New DataSet
        Dim columnName As String = ""
        Dim result As Boolean
        Dim isTemplate As Boolean
        gridDiv.Visible = False
        gridDiv1.Visible = False


        Dim myArray As New ArrayList()
        For Each item As ListItem In chkFields.Items
            If item.Selected = True Then
                myArray.Add(item)
                columnName = String.Concat(columnName, "|", item.Value)
            End If
        Next

        If Trim(txtTemp.Text).Length = 0 Then 'check template name should not blank
            lblMsg.Text = common.ReadResourceValue(ServerPath, "Pleaseentertemplatename")

        ElseIf myArray.count = 0 Then 'check column name should not unchecked

            lblMsg.Text = common.ReadResourceValue(ServerPath, "Pleaseselectcolumnname")
        Else

            Try
                dsData = objAdmin.ShowColumns(cboTemplate.SelectedValue, HttpContext.Current.Session("Project"))

                If dsData.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

                    'Update Template Details
                    result = objAdmin.UpdateTemplate(cboTemplate.SelectedValue, columnName, HttpContext.Current.Session("Project"))

                    If result Then
                        lblMsg.Text = common.ReadResourceValue(ServerPath, "Templateupdatedsuccessfully")
                    End If

                Else

                    'Check Template Name Already Exist or Not
                    isTemplate = objAdmin.IsTemplateExist(txtTemp.Text.Trim, HttpContext.Current.Session("Project"))

                    If isTemplate Then

                        lblMsg.Text = common.ReadResourceValue(ServerPath, "Thistemplatenameisalreadyexist")

                    Else
                        'Save Template Details
                        result = objAdmin.AddTemplate(txtTemp.Text.Trim, columnName, HttpContext.Current.Session("Project"))

                        If result Then
                            lblMsg.Text = common.ReadResourceValue(ServerPath, "Templatesavedsuccessfully")

                            FillTemplate()
                            cboTemplate.SelectedIndex = cboTemplate.Items.IndexOf(cboTemplate.Items.FindByText(txtTemp.Text.Trim))

                        End If

                    End If

                End If
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        End If


    End Sub


    Private Sub FillTemplate()
        Dim objAdmin As New Admin()
        cboTemplate.Items.Clear()
        cboTemplate.DataSource = objAdmin.ShowTemplate(HttpContext.Current.Session("Project"))
        cboTemplate.DataTextField = "TemplateName"
        cboTemplate.DataValueField = "Id"
        cboTemplate.DataBind()
        cboTemplate.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("<New Template>", 0))
        cboTemplate.SelectedIndex = 0
    End Sub

    Protected Sub cboTemplate_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim objAdmin As New TestMagic.Admin()
        Dim dsData As New DataSet
        Dim allCloumn As New DataSet
        gridDiv.Visible = False
        gridDiv1.Visible = False

        lblMsg.Text = " "

        'Get columns by Template & Project
        dsData = objAdmin.ShowColumns(cboTemplate.SelectedValue, HttpContext.Current.Session("Project"))

        For Each item As ListItem In chkFields.Items
            item.Selected = False
        Next

        If cboTemplate.SelectedValue <> 0 Then

            ViewState("columnsName") = dsData.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("ColumnsName").ToString()

            Dim columnsName As String = ViewState("columnsName")
            Dim columns As String() = columnsName.Split("|")

            Dim column As String
            For Each column In columns
                For Each item As ListItem In chkFields.Items
                    If column = item.Value Then
                        item.Selected = True
                    End If
                Next
            Next


            'For Each item As ListItem In chkFields.Items
            '    If columnsName.Contains(item.Value) Then
            '        item.Selected = True
            '    End If
            'Next

            txtTemp.Text = cboTemplate.SelectedItem.Text
            txtTemp.Enabled = False

        Else

            txtTemp.Text = " "
            txtTemp.Enabled = True

            For Each item As ListItem In chkFields.Items
                item.Selected = False
            Next

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Filter TextBox value disappear after postback telerik:RadGrid
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here i found an issue in our code that my colleague had written the code for gridData.DataBind() outside the isPostBack which was wrong, Then after there was a mistake in below code.

```
gridData.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames = New String() {"ID_Data"}

        Dim intVal As Integer = allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns.Count
        For a = 0 To intVal - 2
            Dim boundColumn As New GridBoundColumn()

            boundColumn.DataField = allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns(a).Caption().Trim().ToString()
            boundColumn.HeaderText = allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns(a).Caption().Trim().ToString()
            boundColumn.UniqueName = allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns(a).Caption().Trim().ToString()
            boundColumn.ItemStyle.CssClass = "text2"

            boundColumn.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "GridHeader"
            boundColumn.AllowFiltering = True
            gridData.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn)
        Next
```

Then i changed the code to.

```
gridData.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames = New String() {"ID_Data"}

        Dim intVal As Integer = allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns.Count
        For a = 0 To intVal - 2
            Dim boundColumn As New GridBoundColumn()

            gridData.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn) 

            boundColumn.DataField = allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns(a).Caption().Trim().ToString()
            boundColumn.HeaderText = allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns(a).Caption().Trim().ToString()
            boundColumn.UniqueName = allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns(a).Caption().Trim().ToString()
            boundColumn.ItemStyle.CssClass = "text2"
            boundColumn.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "GridHeader"
            boundColumn.AllowFiltering = True            
        Next
```

The column should be add first. Now changing the code my fiter TextBox hold's the filtered value.

Thanks all..

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of possible reasons for the unexpected behavior of the RadGrid.

1. Data binding

Most common mistake developers make when binding data to RadGrid is when the use the generic `DataBind()` method in combination with the NeedDataSource event of the Grid. This a "must avoid" scenario and is described here [Most common mistake developers make when binding](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-binding/understanding-data-binding/server-side-binding/advanced-data-binding-(using-needdatasource-event)) and here [How to bind RadGrid properly on server-side](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/grid/details/how-to-bind-radgrid-properly-on-server-side)

Telerik components are mainly wrappers to the generic ASP Controls, and those inherit most of the ASP Controls' properties and methods, including the `DataBind()` method.

Developer who are used to work with GridView and other ASP controls, they are used to the classic way of binding data, they follow the same principles when using RadGrid. However, RadGrid is an  extended version of the GridView and it has its own and *recommended* logic for binding data, that is, by using the the NeedDataSource event.

Short story long, when the two are combined, they interfere with each other, one override the behavior of the other.

2. Modifying the Grid's structure Dynamically

There are different events that are recommended to be used to change the structure of the Grid, those are the Init and Load.

Depending on which event is used, a different approach needs to be followed.

See the [Creating a RadGrid Programmatically](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/defining-structure/creating-a-radgrid-programmatically) to find instructions on How-To create a RadGrid programmatically or change its structure and the [Telerik RadGrid lifecycle](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/control-lifecycle/telerik-radgrid-lifecycle) article will help you understand why.

Also, sometimes, if you feel like the code you have wrote is not behaving as you expect, there is a chance the wrong event sequence is used for the purpose. Here is the article explaining more about that: [RadGrid - Event sequence](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/control-lifecycle/event-sequence)

Here are couple of examples that I would like to show:

When using the Init event, the control and its settings must be created every time the page loads

```cs
protected void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // create the Grid object
    RadGrid grid = new RadGrid();
    grid.ID = "RadGrid1";
    grid.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
    grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    //Add Customers table  
    grid.MasterTableView.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
    grid.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "CustomerID" };

    // Attach event handlers on every postback
    RadGrid1.ItemDataBound += RadGrid1_ItemDataBound;

    // create the column object
    GridBoundColumn boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    // column settings
    boundColumn.DataField = "CustomerID";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Customer ID";
    // add the column to the columns collection
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);

    // Add the grid to the placeholder  
    this.PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(grid);
}
```

When using the Load event, only the Grid object, and its events need to be created at every page load. Every other configuration such as adding columns programmatically, must be created only at initial load as the ViewState will take care of them the next time the Grid is present on the page.

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid RadGrid1 = new RadGrid();
    RadGrid1.ID = "RadGrid1";

    // Attach event handlers on every postback
    RadGrid1.ItemDataBound += RadGrid1_ItemDataBound;

    // Add RadGrid to the Controls collection of the placeholder
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(RadGrid1);

    // Configure the Grid settings, add columns, etc...
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        RadGrid1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "CustomerID" };
        RadGrid1.AllowPaging = true;
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        RadGrid1.PageSize = 15;
        GridBoundColumn boundColumn;
        boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
        boundColumn.DataField = "CustomerID";
        boundColumn.HeaderText = "CustomerID";
    }
}
```